# Probability element in subset

Tags: probability

Let be $A$ a set of naturals numbers from $1$ to $N$. Let be $B\subset A$ with $M=\operatorname{card}(B)$.  Is $M/N$ the probability that finds an element belong $M$ choosing randomly any number from $1$ to $N$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, assuming by $M = \operatorname{card}(B)$ you mean  $M =|B|.$

Then the probability of selecting an $n \in B\subset A$ is indeed $$\dfrac{|B|}{|A|} = \dfrac MN.$$